# WP website taking over a minute to load on 000webhost.com was working fine

Tags: performance, http, https

I have a site hosted on 000webhost.com  It's been working fine but now takes over a minute to load.  I'm not seeing any errors but did notice the following:

Request URL: https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Mobile Safari/537.36

Appreciate it if someone could look at the site and suggest a course of action. The refresh response is fine. Looking at network in tools it seems the initial request and a stylesheet for css are taking the most time (over a minute) the rest seem to load as expected

[website](https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/)

Comment: Look in your browser's developer tools, particularly the network tab. Looks to me like `https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/?display_custom_css=css&ver=5.2.2` is taking forever to load for some reason.

Comment: yeah, I got that but what do you do about it? The file  loads, so what's taking so long? What do you look for?

Comment: Frankly, on super-cheap or free web hosts, it may be the server itself that's shitty.